# Silverlight 4 Support for x:TypeArguments

Tags: silverlight, generics, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I've got a generic base page class that I'd like to use with my Silverlight pages. The only problem is that the x:TypeArguments attribute doesn't seem to be working.

The attribute is only applied to the root element of the XAML page, and nowhere else.

The error message I keep getting from the compiler is: `"Using the generic type 'Base.BasePage<T>' requires 1 type arguments"`. This error is always pointing to the generated Page.g.i.cs file.

Here is an example of what my root element looks like:

```
<Base:BasePage x:TypeArguments="ViewModels:MyViewModel">
```

I've had trouble finding good information on whether this is supported in Silverlight 4. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't yet supported in Silverlight.  If you want to include a class in XAML it can't be generic.  You could still have a generic and add it to the Visual Tree from code, but not directly in the XAML.

Comment: Does the situation change in silverlight 5?

Answer (score 0):

This workaround only applies to WPF applications.  Currently Silverlight does not support the x:TypeArguments property that is required in the deriving control’s XAML root tag.

If you must have Silverlight controls that derive from a generic base class you have to do some extra work.  Basically you need to have an extra class in the middle so that the UserControl would derive from a non-generic class

Base class:  public class GenericBase : UserControl

Middle class:  public class MiddleStringControl : GenericBase

UserControl:  public class UserControlWithGenericBase : MiddleStringControl

you may see this web page

[deriving-from-a-generic-base-class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/22/known-issue-controls-deriving-from-a-generic-base-class-must-be-in-separate-assembly.aspx)