# Instantiate a generic page in xaml

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm a newbie in windows phone development, so excuse me if my question is a stupid one.

I've developed a simple generic class intended to be a base class for all the pages in my WP7 applicaion. Here it goes:

```
namespace Subway.Rails
{
    public class Screen<TModel> : PhoneApplicationPage where TModel: class, new()
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(TModel),
                                                                                               typeof (Screen<TModel>),
                                                                                               new PropertyMetadata(new TModel()));

        public TModel Model
        {
            get { return GetValue(ModelProperty) as TModel; }
            set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I am trying to declare a page in XAML using the `x:TypeArguments` directive

```
<rails:Screen x:TypeArguments="models:NotesStorage" xmlns:rails="clr-namespace:Subway.Rails;assembly=Subway.Rails" ...
```

and doubling the base type in the *.xaml.cs file

```
public partial class HomeView : Screen<NotesStorage>
```

I am getting a runtime error

```
Error   7   Using the generic type 'Subway.Rails.Screen<TModel>' requires 1 type arguments  D:\development\labs\mobilelab\Subway.Notes\Subway.Notes\obj\Debug\Views\HomeView.g.cs   37  50  Subway.Notes
```

in the generated file.

Are there any ways to instantiate the generic page in XAML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight 4 Support for x:TypeArguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270351/silverlight-4-support-for-xtypearguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I couldn't find anything stating it officially (it's always hard to find documentation on unsupported features) in general: when it is [not supported in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270351/silverlight-4-support-for-xtypearguments) it isn't available on Windows Phone.

The error messages you are seeing seem to confirm this.