# How can I use a type reference in a XAML / Universal Windows app?

Tags: xaml, syntax-error

I want to encapsulate frame navigation in custom command und use this command declaratively as a static ressource. I found

```cs
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

which expects a type parameter (type of the target page) to navigate to. My first attempt was to use a generic ICommand implementation that passes the type of the target page as generic type parameter. As of [`x:TypeArguments` is not supported for Windows Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521435/1641867), I tried to define a property

```cs
public Type TargetType { get; set; }
```

for the command. But no luck again: if I try to set the property via a xaml attribute

```
`<NavigationCommand TargetType="MainPage">
```

I get a compile-time error saying

```
MainPage is not supported in a Windows universal project
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<NavigationCommand TargetType="ns:MainPage">
```

Where `ns` is an XML namespace prefix declared with `xmlns:ns="using:TheNamespaceInCode"`

(note: the `x:Type` markup extension used in WPF isn't supported in WinRT)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Is there a trick to decipher the completly uninformative error message of the XAML compiler? ;-) At least, it didn't say "Unknown type" or something like that..

Comment: @ventiseis, not that I know of ;)