# Self referencing generic type constraint and XAML in UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, generics, uwp

I am currently working on a UWP application in which one I use [self referencing generic type constraint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/12/generics-the-knee-bone-s-connected-to-the-toe-bone-pattern.aspx) in a PCL.

Here a description of the classes of the PCL.

First, the class that implements the self referencing generic type constraint (this class also implements the `new()` constraints)

```
public abstract class A<T> 
  where T : A<T>, new()
{
  //...
}
```

Then, I have a base class that extends the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` class :

```
public abstract class MyPage<T> : Page
  where T : A<T>, new()
{
  //...
}
```

I also have a base class that extends the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application` class :

```
public abstract class MyApplication<T> : Application
  where T : A<T>, new()
{
  //...
}
```

My UWP classes extends the classes of the PCL describe above in the following way...

First, I have a class `B` that extends the class `A` :

```
public sealed class B : A<B>
{
  //...
}
```

Then, I have the class `App` that extends the class `MyApplication`. The csharp file :

```
public sealed partial class App : MyApplication<B>
{
  //...
}
```

And the XAML file :

```
<custom:MyApplication
  x:Class="My.Project.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:custom="using:My.PCL"
  RequestedTheme="Light"
/>
```

Then, I have a `HomePage` that extends the class `MyPage`. The csharp file :

```
public sealed partial class HomePage : MyPage<B>
{
  //...
}
```

And the XAML file :

```
<custom:MyPage
  x:Class="My.Project.HomePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:custom="using:My.PCL"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
>
```

When I try to compile, I have the following errors (the messages are in french, I tried to translate them in english) :

> Used of generic type `MyApp<T>` needs arguments of type 1 (file App.i.cs)
>
> Used of generic type `MyPage<T>` needs arguments of type 1 (file HomePage.i.cs)
>
> The name `MyApp` does not exist in the namespace `using:My.PCL` (file App.xaml)
>
> The name `MyPage` does not exist in the namespace `using:My.PCL` (file HomePage.xaml)

According to these issues, I need to specify the genereic type into the XAML of the classes `App` and `HomePage`, so here the new  XAML file according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx) :

```
<custom:MyApplication
  x:Class="My.Project.App"
  x:TypeArguments="local:B"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:custom="using:My.PCL"
  xmlns:local="using:My.Project"
  RequestedTheme="Light"
/>
```

and

```
<custom:MyPage
  x:Class="My.Project.HomePage"
  x:TypeArguments="local:B"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:custom="using:My.PCL"
  xmlns:local="using:My.Project"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
>
```

But it does not work. I still have the previous errors... and new ones :

> GenericArguments[0], `System.Object`, on `My.PCL.MyApplication'1[T]` violates the constraint of type `T` (file App.xaml)
>
> GenericArguments[0], `System.Object`, on `My.PCL.MyPage'1[T]` violates the constraint of type `T` (file HomePage.xaml)

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Nothing to do with the XAML. `public sealed partial class HomePage : MyPage<A>` You can't use `A` without a generic constraint, it must be `A<Something>`

Comment: @KooKiz : Sorry, I tried to anonymized the project and made a mistake... I have edited my message... It is `public sealed partial class HomePage : MyPage<B>` and `public sealed partial class App : MyApplication<B>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Given this answer (for Windows 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521435/869621) and your result, I think we can safely assume that generic parameters in XAML still aren't supported in Windows 10.

As a workaround, you can add an intermediate class in the inheritance tree to set the generic constraint:

```
public abstract class BaseApp : MyApplication<B>
{        
}
```

Then make your app inherit from it:

```
sealed partial class App : BaseApp
```

And change your XAML accordingly:

```
<local:BaseApp
    x:Class="My.Project.App"
```

Dirty, but unfortunately there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: so sad... :( Your solution works ! Thk you for your help !

Comment: Does Xaml for UWP support x:TypeArguments already? I still see it generates class without generic arguments in *.g.i.cs file :(

Comment: I see although such solution works in runtime the designer can't instantiate such page based on custom type and still shows errors :( ...

Comment: Generic arguments are not supported in UWP. Please vote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/610869/support-generic-type-arguments-in-uwp-xaml.html).

Comment: Once you get over it, this is not a bad workaround, its 3 (or 1) lines of code into each xaml view that you _really_ want this functionality in. The XAML way to do this is through attached properties but it requires you to use a completely structurally different approach.